# Ac blowing hot air and only works when temp is below 80

Tags: vw, ac, jetta

I have 2016 VW Jetta S. My Ac blows warm air and only blows cold when the car temp says 80 or below. If it’s above that number it won’t get cold. I’ve changed the compressor, condenser, and evaporator. I think whatever is suppose to detect the temp and pressure change might be the issue. Please. My kids and I have been suffering and low on cash as I’m a student. Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Why did you change those parts? Did you have other issues?

Comment: Because I was told to change them so the mechanic did. But no other issue other than that

Comment: Ouch @Tin, that hurts.

Comment: Has the engine coolant temperature sensor even been replaced?

Comment: Check your cabin air filter and/or leaves blocking the vents below the windshield. And have your battery and alternator checked. Pretty much everything depends on clean power.

Comment: No the coolant has not and I will check the filters and battery and alternator

Comment: Ok I did all of the above and nothing came back as an issue

Comment: Can you or someone read the engine coolant temperature (when it gets above 80) through the OBD port?

Comment: How do I read it. Is there a tool I must use or rent?

Comment: Thank you Guys so much for the advice you’ve been giving me

Comment: It's an expensive tool and/or you may need a computer. The best way to do it is asking a mechanic if he can do it. You need to check if the sensor reading is too high, since in modern cars the AC compressor is always either uncoupled from the engine (if there's a clutch) or fully destroked (if the compressor is clutchless) once the engine temperature reading becomes too high. Alternatively, you can try replacing the engine coolant temperature sensor.

Comment: So basically you’re saying a over heating sensor reading from the engine is shutting the AC down? My AC has a clutch by the way

Comment: If it has a clutch it can also be a clutch gap too wide problem. Once the coil heats up the force is no longer enough to keep the clutch hub on the pulley. In that case just remove the clutch hub, adjust the gap width (for example, if the gap width is determined by shims, removing one shim can help) and mount the cluch hub again. Can you measure the clutch gap and/or post a pic of the compressor's clutch? BTW, yes, the control units are programmed to disengage the AC compressor to free the engine of additional load once it overheats.

Comment: Oh ok. I will post all this info in the coming days. I’m gonna wait til I can get a friend to help me

Comment: What about the AC pressure switch? Can a bad one be the issue?

Comment: If it were the AC pressure transducer (it's always a transducer located on the high side, with a variable displacement compressor) an error would show in the OBD. That's why i told you to have an OBD scan done. With advanced enough equipment you can actually read not only the engine coolant temperature sensor's reading, but also the AC system pressure transducer's reading. Anyway i highly doubt a transducer would fail in a way that the AC stops cooling only after the engine warms up enough.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that the Ac setting is on max and when I move it from max going up towards the middle temp it starts blowing heat. I have also checked the compressor and it’s running and spinning while only blowing the warm air. Thought I’d share this last bit on info. I’m going to autozone tomorrow and see if they will do the readings for me

Comment: Do the car have to run for a certain time in order to check coolant reading?